# Fill a data frame with NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataset like myData below:

```
set.seed(1234)

Date <- seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("1990-12-01"), "months")
Date <- rep(Date, 5)

Species <- rep(c("cat", "lion", "tiger", "leopard", "cheetah"), each=12)

Measurement <- rnorm(60)

index <- sample(1:60, 10)

myData <- data.frame(Date[-index], Species[-index], Measurement[-index])
```

Notice myData doesn't have all the possible combinations between Date and Species. There are 10 missing rows. I want to create a new data frame (let's say myData2) where I have all the possible combinations between Date and Species, i.e., myData 2 will have 60 rows. The value of Measurement in myData2 should be its original value, if the particular combination of Date and Species is present in myData, or NA, if this combination is missing.

I'm trying to accomplish this with two nested for loops, but it is not working. I know I'm making mistakes, but I can't figure out what they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `complete` function from `tidyr` package which is designed exactly for your purpose:

```
tidyr::complete(myData, Date, Species)

# Source: local data frame [60 x 3]
# 
#          Date Species Measurement
#        (date)  (fctr)       (dbl)
# 1  1990-01-01     cat  -1.2070657
# 2  1990-01-01 cheetah  -0.5238281
# 3  1990-01-01 leopard  -2.1800396
# 4  1990-01-01    lion  -0.7762539
# 5  1990-01-01   tiger  -0.6937202
# 6  1990-02-01     cat   0.2774292
# 7  1990-02-01 cheetah  -0.4968500
# 8  1990-02-01 leopard  -1.3409932
# 9  1990-02-01    lion          NA
# 10 1990-02-01   tiger          NA
# ..        ...     ...         ...
```

Comment: I'm trying what you said, but I'm getting an error: "Error: cannot join on columns 'Date' x 'Date': index out of bounds"

Comment: Note that your data is not properly named. Rename your data and then use the column names correspondingly.

Comment: Yep. I didn't notice it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We don't need a package.  It can be easily done with `expand.grid` from `base R`

```
merge(expand.grid(Date=unique(myData$Date), 
      Species=as.character(unique(myData$Species))), myData, all.x=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
myData <- data.frame(Date= Date[-index], Species = Species[-index], 
                  Measurement = Measurement[-index])
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(myData)[CJ(Date = Date, Species = Species, unique = TRUE), on = .(Date, Species)]
```

> ```
>           Date Species Measurement
>  1: 1990-01-01     cat  -1.2070657
>  2: 1990-01-01 cheetah  -0.5238281
>  3: 1990-01-01 leopard  -2.1800396
>  4: 1990-01-01    lion  -0.7762539
>  5: 1990-01-01   tiger  -0.6937202
>  6: 1990-02-01     cat   0.2774292
>  7: 1990-02-01 cheetah  -0.4968500
>  8: 1990-02-01 leopard  -1.3409932
>  9: 1990-02-01    lion          NA
> 10: 1990-02-01   tiger          NA
> 11: 1990-03-01     cat   1.0844412
> 12: 1990-03-01 cheetah  -1.8060313
> 13: ...
> ```

It uses `CJ()` (*cross join*) to create all unique combinations of `Date` and `Species` and joins this with `myData`. This is similar to [Akrun's base R approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37893082/3817004).